# How to build a bridge of events between different components in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to solve it

- 1) click mainMidLeft component
- 2) after clicked, to move slideLeftTop component

http://joxi.ru/ZrJBvERH1JVa8r

The problem I dont quite understand how to do this in right way..

Is it okay to create in mainMidLeft a method where I will do somethik like this:

```
move: () => {
   document.querySelector(`.slideLeftTop`).style.position .....
}
```

Comment: You can $emit event to parent or set param in store.

Comment: Never use querySelector, let Vue handle the DOM for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use Vuex State manager with computed methods (getters) and watchers

I have made a working example for you on jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/n4e_m16/wujafg5e/4/

For more info on how vuex works please go to [Here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html)

Please let me know if you need more help :)

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    mainMidLeftState: false,
  },

  getters: {
    mainMidLeftState: state => state.mainMidLeftState,
  },

  mutations: {
    toggleMainMidLeft: (state, payload) => {
      state.mainMidLeftState = !state.mainMidLeftState
    },
  },
})


Vue.component('main-mid-left', {
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  computed: {
    mainMidLeftState() {
      return this.$store.state.mainMidLeftState
    },
  },
  methods: {

    toggleMainMidLeft() {
      this.$store.commit('toggleMainMidLeft')
      //  alert(this.mainMidLeftState)
    },
  }
})

Vue.component('slide-left-top', {
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  computed: {
    mainMidLeftState() {
      return this.$store.state.mainMidLeftState
    },
  },
  watch: {
    mainMidLeftState: function(val) {
      alert("YES, computed property changed and alert have been triggered by watcher in slide top left component")
    }
  },
  methods: {

  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
})
```

```css
div {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <!-- inlining the template to make things easier to read - all of below is held on the component not the root -->
  <main-mid-left inline-template>
    <div>
      <h4>
        main mid left
      </h4>
      <button v-on:click="toggleMainMidLeft()">toggle Main Mid Left State</button>

      <div v-show="mainMidLeftState == true">State is true</div>
      <div v-show="mainMidLeftState == false">State is false</div>
    </div>


  </main-mid-left>

  <slide-left-top inline-template>
    <div>

      <h4>
        slide left top
      </h4>
      <div v-show="mainMidLeftState == true">State is true</div>
      <div v-show="mainMidLeftState == false">State is false</div>
    </div>
  </slide-left-top>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use vuex, you can create a new Vue instance as an event bus (I believe this is mentioned somewhere in the Vue tutorial):

```
const EventBus = new Vue()
```

Import EventBus to where you need it and you can send an event by:

```
EventBus.$emit('event-name', data)
```

And add the following script in created() of your receiver component:

```
EventBus.$on('event-name', ($event) => {
        // Do something
    })
```

I hope this helps |´・ω・)ノ